# Could someone please explain, why I get this error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const cowSound = 'moo';
function makeSound() {
  console.log('My cow goes', cowSound);
  const cowSound = 'baa';
  console.log('My cow goes', cowSound);
}

makeSound();
```

VM174:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'cowSound' before initialization

Comment: The localized `const` cowSound in the method that is hoisted, is not initialized at the time you try to use it.

Comment: @Taplar You can use the answer section to provide an answer. The comment section is there if you want to ask for clarification.

Comment: Surely there is an existing duplicate already.  I don't need points that badly.

Comment: @Taplar, Thank you for your answer, I did not know that variables inside a function get hoisted withing the function